# Gitlab install Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache already installed

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, gitlab

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I have Apache, MySQL, Gitweb and Jenkins already running on there, but wanted to try Gitlab.

I downloaded the package and installed as directed at https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/

When I visit the URL & port I chose (I have wildcard DNS for the server) I get a 404 error.

I have no idea how to make this work as Google only talks about setups from a pristine server. I've never dealt with Ruby or nginx before so have no clue where to even find their logs and configs on a normal setup, never mind a custom one.

Anyone got any ideas how I even debug this? I can't even work out where the config files are, as it's all hidden in the deb (which won't uninstall either).

Contents of my /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb below:

```
# Change the external_url to the address your users will type in their browser
external_url 'http://localhost:8888/'
redis['port'] = 1234
postgresql['port'] = 2345
unicorn['port'] = 3456
```

[Update]

I set up an apache host to reverse proxy to gitlab, and when I hit that, I see a "503 - Service Temporarily Unavailable" error

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6581

The nginx config file is at `/opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/nginx.conf` and you need to change the port manually in that file.

I set the port number for nginx - it seems it was being ignored in the ruby config file. When I restarted everything, it worked.